# Unable to properly edit unicode characters in eXide

Tags: exist-db, exide

I am trying to edit the following xml in eXide editor

```
<root>
    హరి ర్హరతి-హరిః+హరతి, పాపాని, దుష్టచిత్తై రపి-దుష్టచిత్తైః+అపి, స్మృతః,
    అనిచ్ఛయాపి-అనిచ్ఛయా+అపి, సంస్పృష్టో- సంస్పృష్టః,దహత్యేవ-దహతి+ఏవ,హి,పావకః,

    స-సః, గంగా, స-సః, గయా, సేతుః, స-సః, కాశీ, స-సః, చ, పుష్కరమ్,
    జిహ్వాగ్రే, వర్తతే, యస్య, హరి రిత్యక్షర ద్వయమ్-హరిః+ఇతి+అక్షరద్వయమ్,
</root>
```

If I press del key the letter at the cursor is not deleting but some other character got deleted. Does the eXide support unicode characters and respective fonts of the content. Is there any workaround other than editing the xml files in another editor and uploading them to eXist every time a change is needed.

Comment: You have established experimentally that it doesn't...

Comment: It would help if you add the versions of eXist-db and eXide and your browser; improvement are made contineously, eXistdb v3 (to be released soon) might improve the editing.

Comment: Conformed ; I have filed an issue for you https://github.com/wolfgangmm/eXide/issues/123

Comment: existdb v2.2 and the browser is firefox45.0.1. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

the short answer: no it is not possible right now (exist 3.1).

long answer: If you find a way to override eXides font selection which is handled by ACE, and use the browsers or OS native font-substitution mechanism, you should be able to edit the xml in eXide.